# Is it possible to select best hyperparameter in the inner loop of nested CV based on a few measures?

Tags: r, mlr

Is it possible to select best hyperparameter combination in the inner resampling loop of nested CV based on a few measures (multi-criteria evaluation)? If not, is it possible to add a new measure, calculated as a ratio of existing ones? 
I have been reading about makeTuneMultiCritControl, tuneParamsMultiCrit function within the package, but have a problem with understanding on how to apply them within nested resampling.

I would greatly appreciate suggestions in this matter. Greetings

Comment: Have you had a look at the relevant part of [the tutorial](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/advanced_tune.html#multi-criteria-evaluation-and-optimization)? You can combine that directly with nested resampling as shown in the part on general hyperparameter tuning. You only need to call a different function for the tuning.

Comment: Thank you for the response! At first I didn't grasp the idea, but now as I understand I just have to replace the makeTuneWrapper with tuneParamsMultiCrit function after prior selection of control structures for multi-criteria tuning.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I would like to add a new measure (True Skill Statistic) which is based on tpr & tnr. I was wondering if the following code is somewhat close to what is needed

```r
# define a function to calculate TSS
tss.fun = function(task, model, pred, feats, extra.args) {
 predicted <- getPredictionResponse(pred)
 actual <- getPredictionTruth(pred)
 vec <-  ifelse(actual==0 & predicted==0,"TN",
              ifelse(actual==0 & predicted==1,"FP",
                     ifelse(actual==1 & predicted==0,"FN","TP")))
 cm <- table(vec)
 (cm["TP"]/(cm["TP"]+cm["FN"])) + (cm["TN"]/(cm["TN"]+cm["FP"])) - 1
}
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>